# How can I set the return type to be V extends keyof infer U

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an interface that has keys that are primitive types and keys that are arrays of objects:

```js
interface Ifields {
    name: string,
    items: {
        id: number
    }[]
}
```

I'm creating a new interface for an object that will have the following function:

```js
const sublistvalue = rec.getSublistValue({sublistId: 'items', fieldId: 'id', line: 0})
```

I want to create another interface that gets the Ifields interface and only allows me to pass in keys in the interface that are arrays, and fields that are in that array.

```js
const rec = makeRecord() as IRecord<IFields>
rec.getSublistValue({sublistId: 'name', fieldId: 'id', line: 0}) //invalid name is not an array
rec.getSublistValue({sublistId: 'items', fieldId: 'qty', line: 0}) // invalid 'qty' not a field of items

rec.getSublistValue({sublistId: 'items', fieldId: 'id', line: 0})// valid
```

In addition I want the function to have a return type of number.

I'm pretty close:

```js
interface IFields {
    name: string,
    items: {
        id: number
    }[]
}

interface IRecord<T> {
    fn: <K extends keyof T>(x: {
        sublistId: T[K] extends object[]? K: never,
        fieldId:  T[K] extends (infer U)[]? keyof U: never,
        line: number}) => 
        T[K] extends (infer  U)[] ? U : never
}
```

This almost works, but the last requirement is not satisfied.

The return type `U` in this case is `{id: number}`, I need it to be `number`

Here is a link in typescript playground with my current solution:
[link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEZkG8BQz-IhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmANHgcJMZRbgd8sACYUQAV2IAjaM3wBfANoBdHFJzKcoSLEQpUAJgA8AFQB82SchggKugNLIIAD0gg+lZAGsIATwD2MZEYAUdpym3JRCogA2wNSoAn4yVnK2DhBOLl6iAFYQCGDyAPzIVoIQAG7QTDwEMMAQEXyxFPGJyY7OyP6gMNDIAKoAlAVunj59JeVQlVXIUSDkhCLiUFL9yCEEALzG+glJ9m0unSDdUPgD8siFvcjjEkrKCF4g1Mh2yBvYUshwLjq6GIYHk8XpAXh87AA6cz+LBhSLRMCNZAAIlYEHYyIYZlq9SRqL4mJmoHmAAYVsogA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqYnrm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: This works perfectly. I wonder if there is a way to do it without intermediate types. If not I can use this.

Comment: Those intermediate types are there for readability and reusability; I can inline them like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mA89ZN) but that's harder for people to understand and reason about.  If it's okay with you I'll write up my original solution and then add a bit about inlining at the end.

Comment: No problem. I will probably use the inline solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep track of the particular `fieldId` property of the array elements, then you will need `fn()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in that type as well.  Let's keep `K` as the type of `sublistId`, and give the type parameter name `P` to the type of `fieldId`.  Then you can write `I2<T>` like this:

```
interface I2<T> {
    fn: <K extends ArrayKeys<T>, P extends keyof ArrayElement<T[K]>>(x: {
        sublistId: K,
        fieldId: P,
        line: number
    }) => ArrayElement<T[K]>[P]
}
```

where `ArrayKeys<T>` and `ArrayElement<T>` are helper utility types defined like:

```
type ArrayKeys<T> = keyof {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends readonly object[] ? K : never]:
    any }

type ArrayElement<T> =
    T extends readonly any[] ? T[number] : never;
```

The idea is that `K` should only be keys of `T` whose properties are arrays of objects (and note that [`readonly object[]`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) is more permissive than `object[]` so we use that).  So `ArrayKeys<T>` uses [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to include only keys whose properties meet the constraint.

If the compiler were able to reason about generic conditional types like `ArrayKeys<T>` then you could probably just write `P extends T[K][number]` and have the return type be `T[K][number][P]`, since it would understand that `T[K]` is an array type with a corresponding `number` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) and therefore you could [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with a `number` key to get the array element type.  But it can't do that.  So we have to help it out by using a utility type `ArrayElement<>`.  So instead of `T[K][number]` we have `ArrayElement<T[K]>`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
interface I1 {
    name: string,
    items: {
        id: number,
        str: string
    }[],
    other: {
        foo: boolean
    }[]
}
const x = {} as I2<I1>
x.fn({ sublistId: "items", fieldId: "id", line: 0 }) // number
x.fn({ sublistId: "items", fieldId: "str", line: 1 }) // string
x.fn({ sublistId: "items", fieldId: "wha", line: 1 }) // error
// ----------------------> ~~~~~~~ 
// Type '"wha"' is not assignable to type '"id" | "str"'
x.fn({ sublistId: "name", fieldId: "str", line: 1 }) // error
// --> ~~~~~~~~~          ~~~~~~~
// Type '"name"' is not assignable to type '"items" | "other"'
x.fn({ sublistId: "other", fieldId: "foo", line: 2 }) // boolean
```

Looks good. The compiler accepts valid inputs, rejects invalid inputs (`sublistId`s that don't correspond to arrays, or `fieldId`s that don't correspond to the right keys), and returns the expected type.

---

Note that if you don't want to write utility types you could inline the definitions like

interface I2 {
fn: <K extends keyof {
[K in keyof T as T[K] extends readonly object[] ? K : never]: any
}, P extends keyof (
T[K] extends readonly any[] ? T[K][number] : never
) >(x: {
sublistId: K,
fieldId: P,
line: number
}) => (T[K] extends readonly any[] ? T[K][number] : never)[P]
}

which works more or less the same, although it's messier and therefore depends on your use case whether or not it's appropriate.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIEEBOiCG4DS1wGcA8AVAPlgF5YBrLAewDNYBvYWZ2AbXVgEsA7C6u-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-3TRtnWzSD2JcMD-SLRUqBgwd2nguME1VKh1W4EBgHqfFmjaABmLpzhYPoBiGJZUj4NY6G0oF2C4XhVnWQRhFECRFhSUYVDUDRtF0QwTDMSxrFgConDKOxsihWYFmGQyrLoI4OUSeywqc9JXKybxcnyCRWCKJNXF8+x-MhC5YWOU4yXlXigK5V5ot6cDXQBSqy0TCEoVhEhiCOPZJDitIXMyIRku89r0p5LK-KqaEMS1IA)